# Import node_modules members autocomplete in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules

I'm used to Webstorm import's autocomplete where I type the following:
`import {} from 'react'` and when I start typing inside the curly braces I get suggestions from Webstorm. I fail to find extensions in VS Code that do the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: This should work automatically if you are in a js project. Can you try triggering suggestions inside the braces using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> (which is the keybinding for the  `editor.action.triggerSuggest` command)

Comment: Thanks @MattBierner, it seems to work.

Comment: Glad to hear. Moved this information to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode provides suggestions for JavaScript imports but you have to trigger them using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd>. This is the default binding for the `editor.action.triggerSuggest` command